# Does Elastic Basic License include Alerting or not

Tags: elasticsearch

According to their subscriptions [overview](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions) page, Kibana Alerting is supported in the Basic Lisence.

However I'm unable to find/activate the feature on Kibana.

I've been searching the ES forums, can't really find a clear answer whether Alerting is actually available in the Basic license or not.

Btw: security settings is activated in my cluster

Comment: The Kibana Alert is included in the Basic License, but the only [actions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.7/action-types.html) available are loggin the alert or indexing it in elasticsearch (Index and Serverlog), if you want to send an e-mail, a message to slack or use webhook you will need at least a Gold License. What have you tried that didn't work? Did you follow the [steps](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.7/alerting-getting-started.html#alerting-setup-prerequisites) to activate it?

Comment: In this [section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.7/alerting-getting-started.html#alerting-setup-prerequisites) it states two ifs: so if no security is enabled, you can use alerting by only configuring `xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey` setting?